# "Party on sideways" meaning

Tags: meaning

**"This is one of my favourite couples to smoke up, drink down or party on sideways (does that sound weird?) with."**

This appears on a backpacking blog which suggests other blogs to follow. The writer is describing a couple who runs one of these blogs, he knows them personally and this is his description.

Could you explain to me what does "party on sideways" mean?

Comment: The writer is just (jokingly) continuing a series: smoke **up** , drink **down** and... what directions are left?

Comment: @JimMack - That's a great insight. I would have missed that. Maybe this should be an answer. It's pretty obviously correct.

Comment: It's part of a more vulgar expression too: **** me sideways, not meant literally, but as a corollary to smoke *up* (sky high) and drink *down* (under the table).

Comment: It's likely a stylized expression meaning "to party with" like @JimMack said, but without context it could be interpreted as having sexual intercourse. "Horizontal Mambo" by Here Come The Mummies comes to mind.

Comment: @WeatherVane - Or as me old da might have said, "every which way but loose"